# Best practice to store web_client_id from firebase auth?

Tags: android

what is the best practice to store the `web_client_id` that we get from `firebase` in android?
is it in the `string.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several how you can do it. First of all, you can store such things in SharedPreferences (it's convenient to use SharedPreferences in key-value scenarios) -  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Second way - save it in memory. You also can combine these methods (for example, read a value from a memory, but update it in SharedPreferences).

If you need it, you can encrypt a value before saving (via a key in Keystore system).